# Merge [zooming] into [zoom]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoom) has about 5 times the number of questions that [zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zooming) has. The tag descriptions don't suggest any real distinction between the two. Here are the excerpts:

## [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoom)

> Zooming is the act of enlarging something (a document, an image, a map) to view it in greater detail.

## [zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zooming)

> Zooming refers to issues relating to scaling viewed areas in a graphical user interface.

Comment: I don't even think `zoom`/`zooming` are useful tags. How to zoom a view in iOS is an iOS question, how to zoom a view with css is a css question, they don't share anything in common.

Comment: Zooming may not nessacarily be a fully descriptive tag on its own. However in combination with other tags describing the platform it is considerably useful.