# Tag synonym appears in tag suggestions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-synonym-process

I was recently looking for a tag related to the videoing application Zoom. Instead, I could only find the [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoom) tag which is about actual zooming (you know, zoom-in/zoom-out...).

I encountered something strange: while writing `zoom` in the tags box, both [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoom) and [zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zooming) appeared in the suggestions, ***while `zooming` is a synonym for `zoom`!***

[image]

Additionally, The question count that appears above on both tags sums together to the count on the [zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zoom) page (currently 5,678).

For a sanity check, I typed a known synonymized tag:

[image]

`pythonic` doesn't appear as a separate tag.

Is this a bug? Something specific about zooming? What is going on here?

Comment: Not a bug... As far as the system is concerned, [[tag:zoom]] and [[tag:zooming]] are separate tags, each with their own questions. It's just that [[tag:zooming]] was made a synonym of [[tag:zoom]], so any attempt to actually *use* [[tag:zooming]] will remap to [[tag:zoom]]. This can be fixed by a moderator *merging* the [[tag:zooming]] tag into the [[tag:zoom]] tag. That will remove the [[tag:zooming]] tag from the 866 questions that currently have it, thus making the system no longer see it as an extant tag. (We usually hold off on merging until the synonym is proven accurate.)

Comment: I'm looking into this now. I'm not sure that the synonym is actually apt, since a certain human malware situation has made a program called "Zoom" *very* popular. This probably needs some disambiguation. I've broken the synonym mapping entirely for now, so I can see the extent of the confusion.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh I see. So to make sure I understand, creating a synonym only affects from this point onward, not questions tagged in the past? Does merging simply removes the tag from the questions, or replaces it with the merged one? i.e. questions tagged `zooming` will now have `zoom` instead (assuming a merge is done)?

Comment: That's correct; the creation of a synonym only affects from that point forward. Merging removes the "old" tag from the questions and, if it does not already exist, adds the "new" tag to the questions that were tagged with the "old" tag. This is all done when a mod clicks the "merge" button, without any revision history being created. But a mod is required to merge; whereas synonyms can be created by users without mod intervention (although almost never are, since that system is terribly designed).

Comment: In *this particular case*, [[tag:zooming]] was made a synonym of [[tag:zoom]] [back in May 2019 by Bhargav Rao in response to this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324301/merge-zooming-into-zoom). As a matter of course, Bhargav only creates the synonym first, only later going back to do the merge if no objections are raised or issues are found. Presumably, he just forgot in this case to ever go back and do the merge (or, you know, things happened in 2019).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations @CodyGray ! Maybe it is more suitable to actually merge `zoom` into `zooming` and change `zoom` to be about the video app? If you're already checking into this, then maybe you should also be aware that there is a [tag:zoom-api] and [tag:zoomsdk] that seem both to be about Zoom. Funny enough some of the questions there are also tagged with the currently-unrelated `zoom`...

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I'm going to reverse the direction so that [[tag:zooming]] is the "main" tag. Some manual cleanup will still need to be done, to retag any questions that are about [[tag:zoom-api]] but are incorrectly tagged [[tag:zoom]]. However, they'll all be more recent, so the merge of [[tag:zooming]] won't make this any more difficult.

Comment: @CodyGray well I'll be glad to help with any manual clean-up necessary, but one issue still remains. How to handle the video app tagging: [[tag:zoom]], [[tag:zoom-api]] or [[tag:zoomsdk]]. Feels like some synonym/merge should be done between those 3...

Comment: Questions about Zoom will be tagged [[tag:zoom-sdk]]. It has the synonyms [[tag:zoomsdk]] and [[tag:zoom-api]]. All are fully merged. Questions about zooming will be tagged [[tag:zooming]]. I've merged everything that *used* to be tagged [[tag:zoom]] into [[tag:zooming]]. The [[tag:zoom]] tag no longer exists. I'm selectively retagging anything in [[tag:zooming]] that is about Zoom to [[tag:zoom-sdk]] (and/or deleting the off-topic ones). Feel free to help with this selective, manual retagging of [[tag:zooming]].

Comment: @CodyGray My dose of OCD obsession is satisfied for the day :) Thanks for your immediate attention. Should I delete the question or just leave it be? And one last question, assuming such case, how could I see the specific old questions tagged `zooming`? Whenever I searched for it, it simply showed the synonymized `zoom`

Comment: Just leave this question in-place. Everything I described in my last comment should be "live" now. When you asked this question, there would have been no way for you to see the old questions tagged "zooming". That's why I had to break the synonym.