# Rename [stack-overflow] to [stack-overflow-error]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

I think we should rename the [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) tag.

Many users are asking MSO questions on the main site. [specifically these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstack-overflow%5D+migrated%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0&searchOn=3)

There are not much right now, but more could be asked.

I would recommend renaming [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) to [stack-overflow-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-error) to prevent these Meta questions on the main site.

| [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) | [stack-overflow-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-error) |
| --- | --- |
| Ambiguous over if it's the site or an error. | Clearly states it's an error. |
| Directs Meta questions to SO instead of MSO. | Directs meta questions to MSO. |

Can we rename it?

Comment: Some questions in that tag aren't even conceivably related to stack overflows *or* Stack Overflow itself...it's like they just tagged them that way because they were posting *on* Stack Overflow.

Comment: Actually, [stack-overflow] already has a similar synonym, [[tag:stackoverflowerror]] (as well as [[tag:stackoverflowexception]]), just without the hyphens. Wouldn't mind adding hyphens though, makes it much easier to read.

Comment: In general though, see no harm in accepting this request. At the least, it doesn't seem like it could cause further harm.

Comment: "_Directs meta questions to MSO._" I'm not at all convinced by that. Maybe we get a few less questions on that specific tag, but they'll find other tags to abuse. Right now [stack-overflow] makes a nice honeypot.

Comment: I'd use `[stack-overflow-error]` for SO bug reports, on the main site :D I don't think this fixes the problem you illustrate.

Comment: Looks like we need to get the site renamed. That will avoid the confusion between the site and the error. The founders really should have foreseen this problem.

Comment: Not sure renaming is going to change anything, and stack-overflow-error is in most cases redundant, like stack-overflow-error-exception. And what happens when a user has an error in their code instead of wanting to ask a How-To Question? Wouldn't that just fit right into stack-overflow-error, instead of stack-overflow-howto? :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a limit to how much we can hold new users by the hand. At some point they just have to learn and understand how this site works.

You say that the tag [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) is *"Ambiguous over if it's the site or an error"* but this site (well, the main SO) is for programming questions. It is not a meta site. Isn't it obvious that this tag is about the programming error you get when you overflow the stack? You also say that it *"Directs Meta questions to SO instead of MSO"* but the tag's usage guidance clearly states:

> NOT THIS WEBSITE! Use this tag for the error caused by pushing too many items onto the callstack. If you have a question regarding this website, please go to https://meta.stackoverflow.com

If users don't even bother reading that, what makes you think they will not just use `stack-overflow-error` for their meta questions? They will just start typing `stack-over...` and press on the first tag suggestion that pops up.

I think this change and the bare discussion about it is wasting our time over users who wouldn't care and bother to learn about this site and spend 5 seconds reading a one-sentence wiki. I personally watch that tag for a long time and have it in a custom filter so I get notifications on new questions. I have to say that those cases are very rare to begin with and are handled quite easily (and fast).

Comment: I dunno, I figure they'll at least make a passing attempt at reading the tag's _name_...

Comment: On the other hand, you've got a point about making it easier to find the off-topic questions...tags making it easier to find questions you're looking for: working as intended ;-)

Comment: _"they'll at least make a passing attempt"_ You'd think so, wouldn't you? Users never fail to amaze ;-)

Comment: @RyanM I was wondering if to put that second comment in the answer. This mis-use actually helps us find those meta questions easier and migrate them, so it actually has a benefit...

Comment: @RyanM regarding your first comment, I also follow the [[tag:zoom-sdk]] tag to correct possible misuse. Many times it is tagged for questions simply asking about zooming images. Doesn't seem like they bother to even read the names...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I wonder about that, considering that the [tag:zoom] tag exist. Maybe it's that the system suggest them that tag?

Comment: @Braiam `zoom` is a synonym for `zoom-sdk` which might be part of the problem and that might have been a bad example... Still, as Cerbrus said, we shouldn't count on users doing what *makes sense*

Comment: @Tomerikoo what the actual F... that's stupid. Who in the right mind would synonymize a tag that is bound to be misused with a specific and self describing tag?

Comment: @Braiam Mmmm... [Cody](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405013/tag-synonym-appears-in-tag-suggestions)...

Comment: @Braiam I guess there is no way around it. If `zoom` was to be a synonym of `zooming` than I'm pretty sure there would be questions about the Zoom API tagged with `zooming` instead... Just like `stack-overflow` in the OQ, this doesn't really happen that often and I'm following it to fix any mistags

Comment: @Tomerikoo or we could just remove and blacklist zoom/ing and be done with it. There's a very clear way around it ;)

Answer (score 6):

I disagree that all programming posts about programming stack overflows would fit with [stack-overflow-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-error).

For example, questions like "Is there a limit to items on the stack in (programming language)?" or "Is a stack overflow a concern when writing recursive mathematical operations in F#?"

I just made those up and they aren't about stack overflow errors, but they are about stack overflows.

I am not sure what I would do if I started typing `Stack-Overfl...` on the keywords and only saw [stack-overflow-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-error) (and presumably [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-overflow) wouldn't exist on non-meta)